# How to backup WMI/CIM Commands and its related classes

Tags: powershell

WIM/CIM cmdlets includes many subcommands. If I accidentally deleted a class, with Remove-WMIObject/Remove-CimInstance, in these commands, how can I get it back?

**Example:**

step-1

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root/subscription" -Class "NTEventLogEventConsumer"
Remove-WmiObject -Namespace "root/subscription" -Class "NTEventLogEventConsumer"
```

step-2 (an error, because it was deleted)

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root/subscription" -Class "NTEventLogEventConsumer"

Get-WmiObject : Invalid class
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WmiObject <<<<  -Namespace "root/subscription" -Class "NTEventLogEventConsumer"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

So, I want to store and keep orginal WMI files before doing any process. Is it possible?

Comment: WMI repo data is usually part of a so-called "system state backup" - so find a backup product that does system state backup/restore and you're good to go :)

Comment: So, I couldnt import them again manually? @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Depends what backup agent you're using, most have a CLI you can use to kick off backup/restore tasks from a shell script

Comment: But how?, with MOF files or what :D?

Comment: No idea, hence my recommendation to find a backup product that does system state backups :)